# Gradle Tasks for refresh projects

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have several modules included in Root Projects. One module has Gradle Task with gathering some dependencies in a folder.

```
task myTask1 {
   // gathering all dependencies in a some folder
}
```

And another one, using generated resources from that folder

```
task myTask2 {
   // using resource from some folder 
}
```

Now I want to create main task in root Gradle File, which will invoke first and second tasks from the modules.

```
task myTask3(dependsOn: [':module1:myTask1', ':module2:myTask1']) {
    tasks.getByPath(':module2:myTask2').mustRunAfter ':module1:myTask1'
}
```

I see outputs for each task Ok. But in case `myTask2`, I don't have any resources in specified folders, where `myTask1` generated dependencies. So, before starting `myTask2` I should refresh projects (like `Sync with File System` Button) Note, that calling tasks one by one from `Gradle Tasks View` in Idea works perfect.

Comment: So the inputs of task 2 are the output of task 1? Is this always the case?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, that is the point...

Comment: Is task1 a copy task? Does task2 have a type?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, in task1 I have different actions, and in this scope copy. task2 doesn't have type.

Comment: Had a go at an answer...

Answer (score 1):

If you have an example project like so:

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── module1
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── res
│       ├── file1.txt
│       └── file2.txt
├── module2
│   └── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

With `module1` having a copy task:

```
task task1(type: Copy) {
  from "res"
  into "build/output"
}
```

Then you can add a task `task2` to `module2` which has inputs defines as the outputs of `:module1:task1` like so:

```
task task2 {
  inputs.files tasks.getByPath(':module1:task1').outputs.files
  doLast {
    logger.lifecycle('hello')
  }
}
```

From the root project, the first time you run `task2` (using the plain console so we can see the task resolution output) you get:

```
$ gradle task2 --console plain
:module1:task1
:module2:task2
hello

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

So you can see, it ran `task1` first, then ran `task2`

If we run it again:

```
$ gradle task2 --console plain
:module1:task1 UP-TO-DATE
:module2:task2
hello

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

It still runs the 2 tasks in the right order, and as you can see does no work for `task1` as there is no work to be done (none of the files inside `module1/res` have changed)

Is this what you meant?